# How to post comments on your Facebook Fan Page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, request

I'm trying to reply to comments on my Facebook fan page using Graph API.

I can do that sometimes, but other times i get this error: **"Invalid Status Code Returned: 400"**.

Error object:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#1705) There was an error posting to this wall",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1705,
    "fbtrace_id": "BhmMag2JiPk"
  },
  "__debug__": {

  }
}
```

Code:

```
function sendComment(comment_id, text){
    request({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/'+ comment_id + '/comments',
        qs: {access_token:token, debug:'all'},
        method: 'POST',
        json: {
            message: text,
        }
    }, function(error, response, body) {
        //Check for error
        if(error){
            return console.log('Error:', error);
        }

        //Check for right status code
        if(response.statusCode !== 200){
            console.log('Invalid Status Code Returned:', response.statusCode);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.body));
        }
    })
}
```

Anyone know how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Ok. It looks like then I try to comment 'root' comment - everything is fine. But with a nested comment, I get (#1705) There was an error posting to this wall.

Comment: Check the `can_comment` field of the thing you want to comment on first.

Comment: @CBroe can_comment is false in every reply comment for me. Don't know how I can get them true.